# Python Regex matching string between \n and |

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I have a text that has a lot of `\n` and `|` in it.
Here is a sample:

```
this is a sample\n text. This symbol | shows what I am talking about.
This is \n another | sample
```

I want to be able to extract everything that is between `\n` and `|`. For above example this is: `text. This symbol` as well as `another`
How can I do that in Python 2.7?

Comment: is `\n` a literal character or newline character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
s='this is a sample\n text. This symbol | shows what I am talking about.\nThis is \n another | sample'

>>> print re.findall(r'\n([^|\n]*)\|', s);
[' text. This symbol ', ' another ']
```

This regex captures literal `\n` followed by a negation pattern that says:

`([^|\n]*)` which means match 0 or more of any character that is NOT pipe or newline. Square brackets are used for capturing it in a group which will be printed later in `findall` output. It matches a literal `|` in the end.

Or else using lookaheads:

```
>>> print re.findall(r'(?<=\n )[^|\n]*(?= +\|)', s);
['text. This symbol', 'another']
```

- `(?<=\n )` is a lookbehind that means match should be preceded by newline and a space
- `(?= +\|)` is a lookahead that means match should be followed by a space and pipe.

Answer (score 1):

Use capturing group.

```
re.findall(r'\n([^|]*)\|', string)
```

`[^|]*` matches any character but not of a `|` symbol, zero or more times. By default `re.findall` prints the characters which are present inside the capturing group. So it prints out the in-between characters.  `|` is a special meta character in regex which acts like an alternation operator. To match a literal `|` symbol, you must need to escape it in your regex.

Comment: Thanks Avinash. Can you please explain how it works?

Comment: Actually this gives incorrect result for `re.findall(r'\n([^|]*)\|', 'abc\n foo\n bar\n baz | 123')` i.e. `[' foo\n bar\n baz ']` instead of `[' baz ']`